# validation for length and certain words for textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to validate textbox that enable user to enter only for two words which is "NR" and also enable user to enter characters less than 12 length. i dont want to use regular expressions. can i use label to display error message. i already tried this but not work. i put this code in textchanged event :

```
 if ((TextBoxJO.Text != "NR") || (TextBoxJO.Text.Length != 12))
{
    LabelMessageJO.visible = true;

    LabelMessageJO.Text = "Wrong format";
    Button_Add.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    LabelMessageJO.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what the allowed input is supposed to be. You say they can enter two words, `"NR"` and `"less than 12 characters"`. Do you mean they can either enter `"NR"` OR `"<anything up to 12 characters>"` (which is what your words seem to say)? or do you mean `"NR"` OR `"<something exactly 12 characters>"` (which is what your code says)?

Comment: yes. they can enter either NR or anything up to 12 characters. it is possible ?

Comment: yes, just change your `!=` to `>`. But do you realize that, because "NR" is less than 12 characters, it already falls into the second condition? So you don't need to check for it if you're going to allow anything *up to* 12 characters anyway.

Comment: got it thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a CustomValidator.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxJO" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBoxJO" 
    ClientValidationFunction="isValidCustomTextBox" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script>
    function isValidCustomTextBox(oSrc, args) {
        var value = args.Value;
        if ((value == "NR") || (value.length == 12 && value.substring(0, 2) != "NR")) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong in the code:

- `TextBoxJO.Text != "NR"` means that the textbox should be exactly = `"NR"`, as soon as you add anything else after `"NR"`, its False.
- You should check for `!TextBoxJO.Text.StartsWith("NR")` instead.
- `LabelMessageJO.visible = true;` the `visible` part should be `Visible`

  ```
      if ((!TextBoxJO.Text.StartsWith("NR")) || (TextBoxJO.Text.Length >= 12))
      {
          Button_Add.Enabled = false;
          LabelMessageJO.Text = "Wrong format";
          LabelMessageJO.Visible = true;
      }
      else
      {
          LabelMessageJO.Visible = false;
          Button_Add.Enabled = true;
      }
  ```

The code above should accept anything starting with "NR" that is less than 12 characters long.

"NR123456789" will be valid.

"N12345678" will be invalid, because is missing the "R" at the second place.

"NR1234567890" will be invalid because it's lenght = 12 (if you want 12 characters long to be valid, just remove the = sign from `TextBoxJO.Text.Length >= 12`

Comment: no. this is not what i want. i want user can enter exactly NR, if user enter ER it will be invalid. and also user allowed to enter 12 characters. not characters start with NR. the 12 characters can either be FU1234567R89 :) it is possible ?

Comment: I wrote the code based on my understanding of your requirements, can you add say, 5 valid cases and 5 invalid cases to see if I can adjust the code, did you try the code I wrote? because with that code, "ER" would be flagged as invalid. The string can start with either "NR" or "FU" only, or are there any other valid starting strings?